# SharePoint Calculated Column Exception

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint List that calculates various fees and taxes for products. The fees and taxes are 99.9% the same across the board but I have this rare case where these 2 products that need a to have a slightly different rate for one of the fees. Is it possible to assign a different calculation for these 2 products and not affect the calculations for the rest? For example let's say Calculated column for Fee #1 is 2% but in this rare case for these 2 products, I need it to be 2.5%. The data feeds into several apps and dashboards so adding a new field is not ideal, especially since it will only contain data for 2 rows out of the 2,000+ existing rows.

Comment: It should be possible with single column by modifying the existing formula. Can you show us the current formula you are using?

Comment: Here is a formula for one of the columns I am using1.5*SUM([*Base_Price*],[*Tax1*])+SUM([Tax_2 %]/100,[Tax_3 %]/100)*[*Fee1*]+SUM([Tax_2 %]/100,[Tax_3 %]/100)*1.5*SUM([*Base_Price*],[*Tax1*])+1.5*[*Fee2*]+SUM([*Fee1*],[Fee3],[Fee4],[*Fee5*],[Fee6],[Fee7])

Comment: I need the formula above to be multiplied by 2 instead of 1.5

Comment: Let me also clarify, the products each have 25-30 items. I thought about just going to each row and changing the formula which would be about 50-60 rows but I was hoping to put something in place to handle an automatic calculation. With costs rising, I am sure we will start to see more deviations from the standard.

Comment: Use an `IF` statement in your calculated column formula to check if the current row is one of the two products. For ex: `=IF(OR([Title]="Product1", [Title]="Product2"), 
2*(SUM([Base_Price],[Tax1])+[Fee2])+SUM([Tax_2 %]/100,[Tax_3 %]/100)*(2*SUM([Base_Price],[Tax1])+[Fee1])+SUM([Fee1],[Fee3],[Fee4],[Fee5],[Fee6],[Fee7]),
1.5*(SUM([Base_Price],[Tax1])+[Fee2])+SUM([Tax_2 %]/100,[Tax_3 %]/100)*(1.5*SUM([Base_Price],[Tax1])+[Fee1])+SUM([Fee1],[Fee3],[Fee4],[Fee5],[Fee6],[Fee7])
)`